# Prove $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}u^a\nabla u\cdot\nabla\Delta u=C(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|D^2 (u^{(a+2)/2})|^2+\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla(u^{(a+2)/4})|^4)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Assume $u: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function with suitable integrability assumptions. I'm interested in a formal computation, do not worry about integrability properties or smoothness of $u$.

Let $a$ be a constant.

> By integration by parts, how can one prove that the identity 
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}u^a\nabla u\cdot\nabla\Delta u=C(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|D^2 (u^{(a+2)/2})|^2+\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla(u^{(a+2)/4})|^4)$$
>   holds for $C$ some constant that depends on $a$?
>
> For which $a$ does the previous result hold?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Unsuccessful integration by parts.

Comment: What's $D^2$? It doesn't seem to be Hessian since there's a (vector) norm surrounding it.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco No, that's to be intended (with a little of abuse of notation) as  the $L^2$ matrix norm

Comment: What is $\alpha,$ and why should $u^\alpha$ even be well defined? Also, $u$ is any smooth function? No compact support?

Comment: @zhw. You may assume the right integrability assuptions on $u$. Actually all I need is a formal computation.